# How do I see html tags in Unix text browser?

Tags: bash, unix, shell

I want to take a list of images from any web page(my task at university) using unix script. I am new at unix scripting, so all I managed to find was with command: w3m -dump http://www.myweb.com . But this command doesn't give me any html tags so I could know where the images are and to get them with grep. I also tried -dump_source, but it only gives some unknown symbols.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download a file using this syntax:

```
wget -O destination-filename 'http://www.example.com'
```

If you want to pipe this file through another command, like `grep`, just specify an output filename of `-`:

```
wget -O - 'http://www.example.com'
```

If your goal is to download all of the images that a page uses, `man wget` and have a look at the `-p` option.